# Index is outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

i have this code:

```
String Oddelovac = textBox1.Text;                                     
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(file).Skip(radek))
{
    String[] columns = line.Split(Oddelovac.ToCharArray());
    Mnozstvi = columns[poradi_mnozstvi];
    Prod_cena = columns[poradi_ProdCena];
    Ean = columns[poradi_Ean];
    Cislo = columns[poradi_Cislo];
    Nazev = columns[poradi_Nazev];
    Dan = columns[poradi_Dan];
    ng_Doklad = columns[poradi_NG];
    o1 = columns[poradi_o1];
    o2 = columns[poradi_o2];
    zc = columns[poradi_ZC];
    u1 = columns[poradi_U1];
    Od = columns[poradi_Od];
    MJ = columns[poradi_MJ];
    datum_nahrani = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}
```

I have this error:
`index is outside the bounds of the array`   - in cast zc = columns[poradi_ZC];
The error is in poradi_ZC, it have 2 digit...
Example:

```
poradi_o1=8
poradi_o2=9
poradi_ZC=10
```

Have you any ideas?

Comment: You have less than 11 columns in your columns array

Comment: Seems like `columns` has no index `10` - check the length of your array. Also, with your approach you have to make sure that each and every line in your file **will** split into the desired amount of items, otherwise you will run into this exception more often...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic "fix" is to only try to get a value if the array you are fetching from is long enough:

```
zc = (columns.Length > poradi_ZC) ? columns.[poradi_ZC] : string.Empty;
```

...but you have to decide if that makes sense in your case, or if something else is wrong. In any case, that is the reason for your error (columns contains less than `poradi_ZC + 1` elements).

(Remember that array indexes start with 0, so the second element is found with `columns[1]`, and the last with `columns[nrOfItems - 1]`).